# mysql: selecting rows if a number is in a list field (ie. userIDs = "1,2,3", select * from table where 1 in userIDs)

Tags: mysql, list

i store lists of ids inside fields (by list i mean `val1,val2,val3,...`), and i want to select rows from a table where the field has valX in the list.

i thought this would work, but apparently not :(

```
SELECT * 
  FROM userbulletins 
 WHERE 25 IN `currentMessages` 
    OR 25 IN `removedMessages` 
    OR 25 IN `readMessages`
```

currentMessages, removedMessages, and readMessages are fields with ids stored as lists

i've also tried

```
SELECT * 
 FROM userbulletins 
WHERE "25" IN(`currentMessages`)
```

both return nothing (and should return 1 row in my test db)

any idea what i'm doing wrong? or if this is even possible?
thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a denormalized table where the `currentMessages` value can be "val1,val2,val3,..." and you want to find rows where 25 is one of those values?  If so, use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('25', `currentMessages`) > 0
   OR FIND_IN_SET('25', `removedMessages`) > 0
   OR FIND_IN_SET('25', `readMessages`) > 0
```

...but I really recommend normalizing your data to make querying easier.

Comment: i thought about normalizing it, but the website is so huge that adding three tables for this seems like overkill. that would mean three more tables than the one there is now; one each for current, removed, and read messages. thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for this purpose:

```
SELECT * 
FROM userbulletins 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET("25", `currentMessages`)
```

It would also be worth considering if a different design would be better where you don't have a list of values in a single cell. I recommend that you read this Wikipedia article on [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 0):

That's because `IN` doesn't work like that.  In is for a stated list of values or a list resulting from a subquery.

Either you have to have currentMessages expressed as a string, in which case `WHERE currentMessages LIKE '%|25|%' OR currentMessage LIKE '25|%' OR currentMessage LIKE '%|25' OR currentMessage = '25'` will work messily, or you have to have another table (or a few of them), such that it's

```
SELECT * FROM userbulletins
    WHERE 25 IN (SELECT * FROM `currentMessages` WHERE....)
```

--In that case, I'd advise messages(id,[title,content,whatever],status{current,removed,read})

fakeEDIT: The solutions with FIND_IN_SET are better than my LIKE option, but I would still suggest using a table for it.